# An Inequality $\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2}\right)^2\le\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3}\right)^3$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Why is $\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2}\right)^2\le\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3}\right)^3$ with $a_k$ nonnegative

Writing

$\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2}\right)^2=\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_ka_k^{-1/2}\right)^2$

$\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3}\right)^3=\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_ka_k^{-2/3}\right)^3$

and assuming $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k=1$ the inequality is equivalent to,

$\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_ka_k^{-1/2}\right)^{-2}\ge\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_ka_k^{-2/3}\right)^{-3}$

This is almost the power mean inequality, if the exponent on the RHS were $-\frac 32$ instead of $-3$ but if $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k=1$ then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/3}\ge1$ hence $\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_ka_k^{-2/3}\right)^{-\frac32}\ge \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_ka_k^{-2/3}\right)^{-3}$ so we're done

Is there a possibility to solve this more directly

Comment: Both sides are homogeneous of degree $1$. If the left hand side is $0$, it's trivially true. Otherwise, you can assume the LHS is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$3\sum\limits_{i\neq j}\sqrt[3]{a_i^2a_j}+6\sum\limits_{i\neq j,j\neq k,k\neq i }\sqrt[3]{a_ia_ja_k}\geq2\sum\limits_{i\neq j}\sqrt{a_ia_j},$$
which is obvious because by AM-GM $\sqrt[3]{a_i^2a_j}+\sqrt[3]{a_j^2a_i}\geq2\sqrt{a_ia_j}$.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let $n=2$. It is easy to generalize to the case of $n>2$. Let 
$$ a_1=r^2b_1^4, a_2=r^2b_2^4$$
such that
$$ b_1^2+b_2^2=1,b_1,b_2\ge0. $$
Then the inequality becomes
$$ b_1^{\frac43}+b_2^{\frac43}\ge 1 $$
which is easy to prove. In fact, noting $0\le b_1,b_2\le1$, one has
$$ b_1^{\frac43}+b_2^{\frac43}\ge b_1^2+b_2^2=1. $$